# orders of elements and multiplicative inverse module m

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find $ord_m b^2$ if $ord_m a = 10$ and $ab\equiv 1\pmod m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215024/find-ord-m-b2-if-ord-m-a-10-and-ab-equiv-1-pmod-m)

If $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ and if $ord_ma=10$, find $ord_mb^{2}$.

I know that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ is used to find multiplicative inverses, and I know the basics to orders of elements, but I'm not sure how I would go about combining what I know to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't ask a question more than once. If the answers to your original question were not helpful then ask for elaboration in comments and/or provide further context in the question, so that you may obtain answers addressing the specific matters that you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working modulo $\,m\,$:

$$ab=1\,\,,\,\,a^{10}=1\Longrightarrow 1=(ab)^{10}=a^{10}\cdot b^{10}=b^{10}=\left(b^2\right)^5$$

End now the argument.