# What integers have order $6 \pmod {31}$?

Tags: number-theory

What integers have order $6 \pmod {31}$?
The order of $a \pmod {m}$ is the smallest $t$ such that $ a^{t} \equiv1 \pmod {m}$.
I know also that this means $x^{6}\equiv 1\pmod {m}$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Can you solve $x^{30} \equiv 1 \bmod 31$?

Comment: Do you know a primitive root for $p=31$?

Comment: Where did 30 come from?

Comment: 31-1=30.  Someone may have been thinking of a phi function use here would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $31$ is a prime number,

it must have at least one primitive root $g\iff $ord$_{31}g=31-1=30$.

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215024/find-ord-m-b2-if-ord-m-a-10-and-ab-equiv-1-pmod-m/215031#215031), $\displaystyle\text{ord}_{31}(g^x)=\frac{30}{(30,x)}$ where $x$ is a positive integer

So, we need $(30,x)=5\implies x=5,25$

Now, as $2^5=31\equiv1\pmod {31}\implies $ord$_{31}2=5<30\implies 2$ is not a primitive root $\pmod{31}$

As $3^1=3,3^2=9,3^3=27\equiv-4\pmod{31},3^5=3^3\cdot3^2\equiv(-4)\cdot9\equiv-5,$
$3^6=(3^3)^2\equiv(-4)^2\equiv16,3^{10}=(3^5)^2\equiv(-5)^2\equiv25\equiv-6,$
$3^{15}=(3^5)^3\equiv(-5)^3\equiv-125\equiv-1$

$\implies 3$ is a primitive root $\pmod {31}\iff \text{ord}_{31}3=30$

So, we need to find $3^5,3^{25}\pmod{31}$ as one of the values of $g$ is $3$

We have already found $3^5\equiv-5\pmod{31}$

and $3^{25}=3^{10}\cdot3^{15}\equiv (-6)(-1)\pmod{31}\equiv6$

Comment: @Did, please pinpoint the mistake

Comment: @Did, observe that $5^3=125\equiv1\pmod {31}\implies (-5)^3\equiv-1\pmod{31}\implies (-5)^6\equiv(-1)^2\pmod{31}\equiv1$ and $(-5)^2=25\equiv-6\not\equiv1\pmod{31}\implies$ ord$_{(31)}(-5)=6$

Comment: Right. These explanations could be included in your answer.

Comment: @Did, that proof is already there in the link. But, where is your" wrong " message?

Comment: I deleted my "wrong" comment because it was wrong.

Comment: @Did, the proof I've added in the comment is basically an independent verification of my conclusion in the answer. Do you still the link is not sufficient?

Comment: As often it depends on the audience. Since you see fit at the beginning to check that 3 is primitive, the audiences the beginning and the end of the post aim at seem different.

Comment: @Did, thanks for your feedback. Please find the edited version.

Answer (score 10):

**Hints:**

- $x^6-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$
- $x^2+x+1=(x-5)(x+6)\pmod{31}$
- $x^2-x+1=(x+5)(x-6)\pmod{31}$
- Hence $x^6=1\pmod{31}$ if and only if $\prod\limits_{a\in A}(x-a)=0\pmod{31}$ where $A=\{\pm1,\pm5,\pm6\}$

Finally, the set of solutions of the equation $x^6=1\pmod{31}$ is $____$ $+31\mathbb Z$.

**Edit:** Once this low-tech approach is mastered, one can note that $A$ lists exactly the divisors of $31-1=30$ and look for [some general result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) explaining this "coincidence".

Comment: I guess you mean $+31\mathbb Z$ at the end.

Comment: @user1 Indeed. Thanks.