# Can I find $r$, if $r^m\equiv 1 (\bmod 18)=6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

**Recall.**

- Definition $1$. $Ord_n(a)$ is the smallest number $m$ st. $\quad a^{m} \equiv 1(\bmod n)$
- Definition $2$. We say $r$ is a primitive root modulo $n$ if $\operatorname{Ord}_{n} (r)=\phi(n)$
- Note: $\left\{1,r, r^2,..., r^{\phi(n)-1}\right\}=U_n$

> I want to find $r$ such that $ord_{18} (r)=\phi(18)=6$, that is we get by definition 1: $r^{m} \equiv 1(\bmod 18)=6$, so hence can I find $r$?

Comment: The expression in your final sentence makes no sense. Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: @BillDubuque I edited question.

Comment: the question still does not make sense:  $1(\bmod18)=6$?!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, okey... if $ord_{18}(r)=6$ then how can i find r?

Answer (score -3):

As $(r,18)=1,(r,6)=1$

As $\phi(18)=6,$ord$_{18}r$ must divide $6$

Now $5^2\equiv7\not\equiv1,5^3\equiv-1\not\equiv1\pmod{18}$

$\implies$ord$_{18}5=6$

Finally use

[What integers have order $6 \pmod {31}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462367/what-integers-have-order-6-pmod-31)

Comment: How did you think $5^2=7, 5^3=-1$?

Comment: @James, $$5^2=7+18\equiv7\pmod{18}$$