# Show that $\alpha = (\omega_6)^5$ is a generator for the set of sixth roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\omega_6 = e^{i{\dfrac{2\pi}{6}}}$. We say that $\omega_6$ is a generator of the set of sixth roots of unity because every sixth root of unity can be written in the form $(\omega_6)^k$ for some positive integer $k$.

Now define $\alpha = (\omega_6)^5$.

$(1)$ Show that $\alpha$ is also a generator for the set of sixth roots of unity.
$(2)$ Are there any other generators of the sixth roots of unity? Justify.

I'm not sure how to start on this question, can anyone give me some hints to start off?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534693/show-that-k-is-also-a-primitive-element-if-and-only-if-gcdk-q-1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\omega_6^6=1$. Furthermore, you know that $\gcd(5,6)=1$ so Bézout's identity tells you that you can find $(k,l)$ integers such that $5k+6l=1$. Consequently,
$$ \omega_6^{5k+6l}=\omega_6^1=(\omega_6^{5})^k(\omega_6^{6})^l=(\omega_6^{5})^k $$
So there exists an integer (maybe negative, but is it a real problem...?) such that $(\omega_6^{5})^k = \omega_6$.
Could you finish with that ?

Comment: In fact you can take $k=5$ and $l=-4$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how we are supposed to be solving this math 300 question. http://people.math.carleton.ca/~ckfong/C2.pdf

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here, we're trying to avoid external links in answers because if there is a problem with your link then your answer will be totally useless. Furthermore, the pdf contains 7 pages, you may want to be a little more precise...