# Trouble with Primitive Roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So, we've been learning about primitive roots, fun... But i'm still having trouble with it and this is a homework problem that i've been trying to solve for the past hour. So how do you do it, i'm still shady on roots and residues. do you do legendre symbol?

oh and if you can give me a detailed proof thatll be great.

6 is a primitive root mod 41. So how many residues mod 41 have order 7? Find the least positive residues of all order 7 mod 41

Comment: Just found : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608777/it-is-known-that-6-is-a-primitive-root-of-41-find-the-least-positive-residues-o

Answer (score 1):

Let me denote ord$_ma$ as [Multiplicative order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $a\pmod m$

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215024/find-ord-m-b2-if-ord-m-a-10-and-ab-equiv-1-pmod-m/215031#215031), ord$\displaystyle _{41}(6^n)=d=\frac{40}{(40,n)}$ as 
ord$\displaystyle _{41}(6)=41-1=40$

Now, observe that $d$ must divide $40$